# Parsing XML with namespaces with Karate

Tags: karate

Does Karate support parsing of XML with namespaces in the nodes?

```
<samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="samlp:Success"/>
</samlp:Status>
```

For example, how do I parse the above and check the value of StatusCode is "Success"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
* def temp = 
"""
<samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="samlp:Success"/>
</samlp:Status>
"""
* match temp/Status/StatusCode/@Value == 'samlp:Success'
```

Path expressions don't need the prefix.

There are a set of examples here: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature)